# Google chrome not rendering the background gradient at all

Tags: google-chrome, background, css

I was reading this article http://www.sitepoint.com/using-unprefixed-css3-gradients-in-modern-browsers/ .I created this little demo of what this article teaches.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Css Gradients</title>
        <style>
            .demo{
                height: 200px;
                width: 400px;
                margin-bottom: 10px;
                background: linear-gradient(to right,red,yellow);
                /*background: linear-gradient(23deg,red,yellow);*/
            }
            #radial{
                /*background: radial-gradient(at center,red,yellow);*/
                background: radial-gradient(circle closest-corner,red,yellow);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="demo"></div>
        <div class="demo" id="radial"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now the problem is,Firefox is rendering the background gradient correctly but Google Chrome(version 22) is not rendering the background gradient at all.See the screenshots
[image: Firefox][image: Chrome]

Comment: What is the point of this thread, do you have a question?

Comment: The question is loud and clear.I want to know why Chrome is not rendering the vendor prefixed free background gradient when Firefox is

Answer (score 0):

At the moment (Chrome 24 / Safari 6) Webkit still have not added support for unprefixed css3 gradients yet.
This is a bit sad, if you consider the fact that even IE10(!) uses unprefixed syntax already.

Reference: http://caniuse.com/#search=grad